# List on scroll giving unexpected results

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

I have made a custom list view with help of BaseAdapter.Now i have one condition to check and based on that condition i have to hide unhide the button in the list.At the start it works properly but when i scrolls the list the button is not at its desired place.I know this is due to refressing of list but please can you suggest me how to overcome it as i am new to android.

Code

```
public class RecentDocumentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    Activity activity;
    DbHandler dbHandler;
    DbModel dbModel;
    private Context context;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private String[] shareArray;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private ArrayList<DbModel> alGetRecentFiles;
    private Bundle bundle;


    public RecentDocumentAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, ArrayList<DbModel> alGetRecentFiles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.alGetRecentFiles = alGetRecentFiles;
        bundle = new Bundle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return alGetRecentFiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recent_docs_custom_list, viewGroup, false);
            holder.docsImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_recent_docs_image);
            holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_recent_name);
            holder.tvPostedOn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_recent_posted_on);
            holder.btShare = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_recent_share);
            holder.btFav = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_recent_fav);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getCheckType() == 2) {
                holder.btShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        holder.tvTitle.setText(alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getTitle() + alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension());
        holder.tvPostedOn.setText(alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getPostedOn());

        if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".jpeg") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".png") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".gif") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".tiff")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".doc") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".docx")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.docx);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".xls") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".xlsx")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.excel);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".ppt") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".pptx")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ppt);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".pdf")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pdf);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(".txt")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.txt);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("3gp") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("mp4") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("mkv") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("wmv") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("flv") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("avi") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("mpeg") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("mov") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("divx") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("div")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.video);
        } else if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("mp3") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("wma") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("aac") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("wav") || alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension().equalsIgnoreCase("m4a")) {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
        } else {
            holder.docsImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.help);
        }


        if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFavourites().equals("1")) {
            holder.btFav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        } else {
            holder.btFav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        holder.btShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bundle.putString("docId", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getDocId());
                bundle.putString("title", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getTitle());
                bundle.putString("path", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFilePath());
                bundle.putString("ext", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileExtension());
                bundle.putString("fileName", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getFileName());
                bundle.putInt("hasPassword", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getHasPassword());
                bundle.putString("password", alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getPassword());
                fragmentTransaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ShareWithinpocketDocs shareWithinpocketDocs = new ShareWithinpocketDocs();
                shareWithinpocketDocs.setArguments(bundle);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, shareWithinpocketDocs, "shareWithinPocketDocs");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("shareWithinPocketDocsBack").commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView docsImage;
        private TextView tvTitle, tvPostedOn;
        private Button btShare, btFav;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to visible share button on else case :

```
if (alGetRecentFiles.get(i).getCheckType() == 2) {
    holder.btShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
    holder.btShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**Note :** Use [equals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) for String comparison instead of ==